# Brightness won't change on Ubuntu 16.04 Macbook Air 13.3

Tags: 16.04, brightness, macbook, backlight

I have MBA(2016) and I fully installed **Ubuntu 16.04.1** on it. I used to change brightness with my function keys. Suddenly it doesn't work now. The thing is that my keys are working, Ubuntu shows me that I dim my brightness but it doesn't change the brightness.(my backlight keys and functions are working)

```
$ ls -a /sys/class/backlight
.  ..  acpi_video0  intel_backlight
```

Comment: Please run `ls -a /sys/class/backlight` and add the output to your question.

Comment: @Hölderlin updated.

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for text you can copy and paste. Instead, copy, paste into your question, select it with mouse, press `{}` button in the editor to format it properly.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex sorry, edited.

Comment: Could you also be add the output of `lspci -nnk | grep "VGA" -A2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the file `brightness` in both directories (interfaces) `acpi_video0` and `intel_backlight` via the following command:

```
sudo bash -c "echo 5 > /sys/class/backlight/xxx/brightness;"
```

If one of the changes affects your backlight create (if not exists) `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` or better `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` and add the following lines where "xxx" belongs to your interface:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Card0"
    Driver      "intel"
    Option      "Backlight"  "xxx"
EndSection
```

Restart your computer and see if works now. 
You can read also [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/backlight).

Comment: Applied both brightness options and it seems like the intel_backlight option solved the brightness problem. Thank you.