# How to switch between options in `/sys/class/backlight` to solve brightness problem?

Tags: brightness, acpi

OS : Ubuntu - 18.04 LTS

I have 2 symbolic links in `/sys/class/backlight/` directory.

```
acpi_video0 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/backlight/acpi_video0/
nv_backlight -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/drm/card0/card0-LVDS-1/nv_backlight/
```

The brightness hotkeys change the value of `acpi_video0/brightness`. But that doesn't actually change the display's brightness.

But, manually changing the value of`nv_backlight/brightness` actually change the display's brightness.

So, linking the hotkeys to `nv_backlight` instead of `acpi_video0` will solve my problem, but I don't know how to do it.

Edit: The pop-up slider progress bar appears on the screen on the operation of the Fn keys for brightness(hotkeys).

Edit:

1. Input:

   ```
   cat /sys/class/backlight/nv_backlight/max_brightness
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   100
   ```
2. Input:

   ```
   cat /sys/class/backlight/nv_backlight/actual_brightness
   ```

   Output(this value changes automatically to the same value, I manually gave into `/sys/class/backlight/nv_backlight/brightness`):

   ```
   10
   ```
3. Input:

   ```
   cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/max_brightness
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   15
   ```

Comment: When you operate the Fn keys for bright up/down does the pop up slider progress bar display on screen?

Comment: Did you try `acpi_backlight=vendor` in the answer below? Did it work?

Comment: No, when I do `acpi_backlisht=vendor`, the `acpi_video0` option goes away and a new option `sony` comes in and the hotkeys reflect changes in `sony/brightness`, with no actual display brightness change. The `nv_backlight` option remains though and the manual changes to it still give me the actual change in brightness.

Comment: OK. It's too late tonight but tomorrow night I'll start writing a script that will take changes to `acpi_video0` and pump the equivalent percentage into nVidieo backlight.

Comment: Thanks, WinEunuuchs2Unix. I tried redirecting the symbolic link. But it gives me an unauthorized operation error.

Comment: Could  you redirect anyway?  Is `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness/max_brightness` 100 as well? It could be as high as 7500 as is the case in my laptop which isn't measuring maximum in percentage.

Comment: No, I couldn't redirect it. And I have edited the question with the information said you wanted.

Comment: I revised the answer last night with a script that should take care of the problem.

Comment: I've found another answer that may work for you with a lot less effort than the answer I wrote: https://askubuntu.com/questions/864134/brightness-wont-change-on-ubuntu-16-04-macbook-air-13-3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Bash script `redirect-brightness`

Your problem is function keys to increase/decrease brightness are updating `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness` instead of `/sys/class/backlight/nv_backlight/brightness`

The original request was to intercept the function keys and use them to control the `nv_backlight` driver. The problem with this is:

- Tricky `udev` scripts
- No pop-up notification slider displaying brightness without complicated Python scripting.

The solution is to use `inotify` to monitor changes to `acpi_video0`. Then calculate the brightness percentage and apply that same percentage to `nv_backlight`.

In the bash script below you need to set:

```
WatchDriver="/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness"
PatchDriver="/sys/class/backlight/nv_backlight/brightness"
```

Place the script in `/usr/local/bin` and make it executable using:

```
chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/redirect-brightness
```

First run the script from the command line using

```
redirect-brightness -l
```

If there is a problem check the log file using:

```
cat /tmp/redirect-brightness.log
```

If all works well add `redirect-brightness` to your startup applications.

### `redirect-brightness` bash script

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# NAME: redirect-brightness
# PATH: /usr/local/bin
# DESC: Redirect to correct driver when Ubuntu is adjusting the wrong
#       /sys/class/DRIVER_NAME/brightness

# DATE: June 13, 2018. Modified June 14, 2018.

# NOTE: Written for Ubuntu question:
#       https://askubuntu.com/q/1045624/307523

WatchDriver="/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight"
PatchDriver="/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight"

# Must be running as sudo
if [[ $(id -u) != 0 ]]; then
    echo >&2 "Root access required. Use: 'sudo redirect-brightness'"
    exit 1
fi

# inotifywait required
type inotifywait >/dev/null 2>&1 || \
    { echo >&2 "'inotifywait' required but it's not installed.  Aborting."; \
      echo >&2 "Use 'sudo apt install inotify-tools' to install it.'"; \
      exit 1; }

# Was right watch driver directory name setup correctly?
if [[ ! -d $WatchDriver ]]; then
    echo >&2 "Watch directory: '$WatchDriver'"; \
    echo >&2 "does not exist. Did you spell it correctly? Aborting.'"; \
    exit 1;
fi

# Was right patch driver directory name setup correctly?
if [[ ! -d $PatchDriver ]]; then
    echo >&2 "Redirect to directory: '$PatchDriver'"; \
    echo >&2 "does not exist. Did you spell it correctly? Aborting.'"; \
    exit 1;
fi

# Get maximum brightness values
WatchMax=$(cat $WatchDriver/max_brightness)
PatchMax=$(cat $PatchDriver/max_brightness)

# PARM: 1="-l" or "--log-file" then write each step to log file.
fLogFile=false
if [[ $1 == "-l" ]] || [[ $1 == "--log-file" ]]; then
    fLogFile=true
    LogFile=/tmp/redirect-brightness.log
    echo redirect-brightness LOG FILE > $LogFile
    echo WatchMax: $WatchMax PatchMax: $PatchMax >> $LogFile
fi

SetBrightness () {
    # Calculate watch current percentage
    WatchAct=$(cat $WatchDriver/actual_brightness)
    WatchPer=$(( WatchAct * 100 / WatchMax ))
    [[ $fLogFile == true ]] && echo WatchAct: $WatchAct WatchPer: $WatchPer >> $LogFile
    # Reverse engineer patch brightness to set
    PatchAct=$(( PatchMax * WatchPer / 100 ))
    echo $PatchAct | sudo tee $PatchDriver/brightness
    [[ $fLogFile == true ]] && echo PatchAct: $PatchAct >> $LogFile
}

# When machine boots, set brightness to last saved value
SetBrightness

# Wait forever for user to press Fn keys adjusting brightness up/down.
while (true); do
    inotifywait --event modify $WatchDriver/actual_brightness
    [[ $fLogFile == true ]] && \
        echo "Processing modify event in $WatchDriver/actual_brightness" >> $LogFile
    SetBrightness
done
```

---

## Original Answer June 11, 2018.

#### Work In Progress Answer

There are many nVidia users with similar problems in Ubuntu 18.04:

- [Brightness on laptop MSI GT72VR in Ubuntu 18.04 with NVIDIA GTX 1060 Mobile doesn't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030526/brightness-on-laptop-msi-gt72vr-in-ubuntu-18-04-with-nvidia-gtx-1060-mobile-does)
- [computer doesnt wake from suspension and couldnt change the brightness](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042809/computer-doesnt-wake-from-suspension-and-couldnt-change-the-brightness)
- [Brightness control missing when using Nvidia drivers but re-appears with X.Org](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042069/brightness-control-missing-when-using-nvidia-drivers-but-re-appears-with-x-org)
- [Xubuntu 18.04: make Fn brightness keys work with /sys/class/backlight/nv_backlight/](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1041051/xubuntu-18-04-make-fn-brightness-keys-work-with-sys-class-backlight-nv-backlig)
- [How to alter backlight driver in lubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1041145/how-to-alter-backlight-driver-in-lubuntu)
- [Brightness on laptop MSI GT72VR in Ubuntu 18.04 with NVIDIA GTX 1060 Mobile doesn't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030526/brightness-on-laptop-msi-gt72vr-in-ubuntu-18-04-with-nvidia-gtx-1060-mobile-does)
- [NVIDIA display issue with brightness control and video playback](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031541/ubuntu-solution-for-the-nvidia-display-issue-on-brightness-control-and-video-pla)
- [Unable to change the screen brightness](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028979/unable-to-change-the-screen-brightness)
- [The brightness of laptop screen cannot be adjusted with either the buttons or the slider. Edit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1010405/the-brightness-of-laptop-screen-cannot-be-adjusted-with-either-the-buttons-or-th)

---

### Before writing a script

I can write a script to mimic changes to /acpi_video and populate /nv_backlight but before I do try this:

- Edit `/etc/default/grub`.
- Find `quiet splash`
- Add behind splash: `acpi_backlight=vendor`
- Save the file
- Run `sudo update-grub`

According to this answer it should work for you: [Xubuntu 18.04: make Fn brightness keys work with /sys/class/backlight/nv_backlight/](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1041051/xubuntu-18-04-make-fn-brightness-keys-work-with-sys-class-backlight-nv-backlig/1041585#1041585)

---

### Wayland

Brightness doesn't work under Wayland. Make sure you aren't using it. See: [The brightness of laptop screen cannot be adjusted with either the buttons or the slider. Edit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1010405/the-brightness-of-laptop-screen-cannot-be-adjusted-with-either-the-buttons-or-th/1011557#1011557)

Comment: The script does the work. But there is a small bug in `SetBrightness ()`. It should be `PatchAct=$(( PatchMax * WatchPer / 100 ))`. Thanks to the entire support.

Comment: Unfortunately in mobile for next 10 hours. I'll test and revise tonight. Feel free to add new comments in the meantime.

Comment: @boobalan You were right about the need to swap the watched percentage and `100` variables. I also corrected typos with nv_video (s/b nv_backlight) and extra `/brightness` in `/brightness/brightness`. If you are happy remember to click the grey check mark next to the answer. This will give others confidence to try out the script for themselves. It was fun developing this script. Thanks!

Comment: If the script is run manually it does work. But if it is added to the startup applications, it doesn't work. I guess there is a problem with giving sudo permissions to startup applications. For your information, I gave `redirect-brightness` as the application command.

Comment: There are many ways to call during startup. One is with cron. Create the file `/etc/cron.d/backlight` containing line 1: `SHELL=/bin/sh` line 2: `PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin` line 3: `@reboot   root    /usr/local/bin/redirect-brightness`

Comment: That solves the entire problem. Thanks a lot, WinEunuuchs2Unix. It was very helpful.