# Brightness fn keys not working new HP gaming laptop

Tags: drivers, grub2, nvidia, brightness

I know This has been asked to death. I have dealt with it before on other laptops.

And I have tried al these combinations in `/et/default/grub` and run a `sudo update-grub` reboot, test, fail.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux"

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset acpi_backlight=vendor"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet video.use_native_backlight=1"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet acpi=strict"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

I tried creating a `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` [source](https://askubuntu.com/a/862156/208343).

So what's next?

It's a [HP Pavilion 15-cx0670nd](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c06067266?jumpid=reg_r1002_usen_c-001_title_r0002).

- Intel Core i7-8750H
- GeForce GTX 1050 Ti
- Intel Mobile HM370

Comment: This answer might be helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045624/how-to-switch-between-options-in-sys-class-backlight-to-solve-brightness-prob/1045763#1045763

Answer (score 0):

I own the same model laptop and also experience this issue. Nothing seemed to work ..

Today I installed Ubuntu 19.04 to a USB stick and the function keys for the brightness worked out of the box! However, when I upgraded my Ubuntu 18.04 to 19.04 it did not work, neither did installing a 'clean' 19.04 over my upgraded version.

Since my clean USB installation of 19.04 did work you might want to give that a shot.

Edit: Seems to be working on my upgraded version as well now.

Comment: Does your SD card reader work under Ubuntu? Because that also is not working.
Also can you share the content of your `/et/default/grub` file?

Comment: Just installed clean on my primary ssd, works fine as well. All I did was:

Install Ubuntu 19.04 (with third-party software enabled), once booted enable Canonical Partners repository, sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade, reboot

Comment: After another reinstall I noticed that the brightness issue might be caused by iio-sensor-proxy being faulty or missing. You might want to try
sudo apt-get remove iio-sensor-proxy
(reboot)
sudo apt-get install iio-sensor-proxy
(reboot)

fyi: The SD card reader does not work under linux, apparently nobody has a working driver for this specific one.

Comment: Yeah, the SD-card also doesn't work. I've just accepted that it doesn't work..