# fn key combinations not working

Tags: keyboard, hp, brightness, 18.10, function-keys

I installed Ubuntu 18.10 on my HP EliteBook x360 1030 G3 and can't get all fn-combinations to work.

What works: Volume up/down, Mute, Airplane mode
What not works: Brightness up/down, Microphone mute

The often stated kernel parameters as listed [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1093016/774341) aren't resolving this issue.

Trying the command `showkey -k` revealed some strange behaviour: For all combinations not working a press and release with the same keycode (465) is generated. The other combinations result in different codes.

When running `xev` or `acpi_listen` no event is listed for the malfunctioning combinations.

Would be great if there is a way to get any reaction for this key combinations.

Comment: Refreshing the topic: did you get to any conclusion? I am facing the same issue with hp 1040 g5 on both Ubuntu 18.04 and Ubuntu 20.04. What is worst the built in mic doesn't work and I wonder if it is related to not working mic mute key (xev and acpi_listen doesn't show any event for this key) or it is a different issue.

Comment: There were some bugs opened on launchpad. But not really a satisfying solution...

https://bugs.launchpad.net/linux/+bug/1806681

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1841039

Answer (score 4):

A power reset worked for me!
It fixed all hotkeys troubles, AND also a problem with no speaker sound after plugging and unplugging headphones.
Running Ubuntu 20.10, see

https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c01684768

---> press and hold the Power button for 15 seconds to reset.
then all hotkeys were fine.

Comment: I second that. A power reset on a HP notebook worked for me too.

Comment: none of the function buttons were working on my Elitebook G10 after an Ubuntu system update and this fixed it for me